# click event in angular on transcluded children

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-transclude

I'm trying to fire a click event on a transcluded child element in my directive. It isn't working. I seem to have lost access to parent scope for some reason.

```
app.controller('myController', [
    '$scope',
    '$log',
    '$q',
    function ($scope, $log) {
      $scope.delete = function(){
        $log.log('delete clicked');
      };

      $scope.whatever = function(){
        $log.log('whatever clicked');
      };
    }
  ]);


  <!-- directive markup -->
  <span class="ui-menu-action">
    <span class="trigger" ng-click="showMenu = !showMenu">
       <i class="sl-icon sl-icon-box-arrow-down"></i>
    </span>
    <div class="actions" ng-show="showMenu" ng-mouseenter="cancelHide()"></div>
  </span>


  <!-- calling the directive -->
    <ui-menu-action>
      <ul>
        <li><a href ng-click="delete()">Delete</a></li>
        <li><a href ng-click="whatever()">Whatever</a></li>
      </ul>
    </ui-menu-action>


  app.directive('UiMenuAction', [
    '$http',
    '$tooltip',
    '$log',
    '$rootScope',
    '$timeout', function($http, $tooltip, $log, $rootScope, $timeout){
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        //scope: {},
        transclude: true,
        templateUrl: './scripts/modules/ui/templates/ui.menu.action.html',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl, transclude){
          var to;
          scope.showMenu = false;
          scope.hideOnPageClick = attrs.hideonpageclick;

          $rootScope.$on('pageClick', function(e, $event){
            var isMenuClick = !!$($event.target).parents('.ui-menu-action').length;

            if ( scope.hideOnPageClick && !isMenuClick ) {
              scope.showMenu = false;
            }
          });

          scope.hideMenu = function(){
            if ( scope.hideOnPageClick ) return;

            to = $timeout(function(){
              scope.showMenu = false;
            }, 400);
          };

          scope.cancelHide = function(){
            if ( scope.hideOnPageClick ) return;

            if ( to ) {
              $timeout.cancel(to);
            }
          };

          transclude(scope.$parent, function(clone, scope) {
            element.find('.actions').append(clone);
          });
        }
      };
    }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

why dont you just remove

```
      transclude(scope.$parent, function(clone, scope) {
        element.find('.actions').append(clone);
      });
```

And add ng-transclude to your markup

```
<div class="actions" ng-transclude ng-show="showMenu" ng-mouseenter="cancelHide()"></div>
```

Comment: I did that although better I still have the same problem. Events in the transcluded markup do not bubble up to the parent scope the directive was called in.

Comment: What do you mean "Events in the transcluded markup do not bubble up to the parent scope the directive was called in"  AFAIK, this only occurs when you have an isolated scope and in your directive, you've commented out the scope.